# Object value gets incorrect data but the data is still retrievable with the key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've built a tool where people can import a csv file and then it creates < p > tags on the page based on the imported text. 
I'm trying to assign the value from my list of imported data to the model attached to the tag but i always seem to get the LAST value from my imported list.

I've put in some logs to show how it's still able to get the value BUT it is not correct inside the object.

```
for (var row in $scope.importedData) {
    for (var column in $scope.importedData[row]) {

        //Imported value shows "Laurent"
        console.log($scope.importedData[row][column]);

        for (var i in $scope.template.textboxes) {
          if ($scope.template.textboxes[i]._id === $scope.importables[column]._id) {
            $scope.template.textboxes[i].value = $scope.importedData[row][column];          

            //Object value shows "Sukh"
            console.log($scope.template.textboxes[i]);

            //value key shows "Laurent"
            console.log($scope.template.textboxes[i].value);
            break;
          }
        }

        //Below uses Underscore.js but the result is the same.
        //_.findWhere($scope.template.textboxes, {_id: $scope.importables[column]._id}).value = $scope.importedData[row][column];

  }

}
```

here is the output of the console, you can see that the value "Laurent" is preserved, however not inside the object. In the object it's "Sukh", the last value of my imported data:
[image]

I have no clue how it is getting the last "row" value.

To my great annoyance, the snippet I made in here works perfectly:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ImportCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.importedData = {
  "0": {"0": "Laurent", "1": "IT", "2": "1234"},
  "1": {"0": "Johnny", "1": "Production", "2": "2345"},
  "2": {"0": "Beatrice", "1": "Accounting", "2": "4567"},
  "3": {"0": "Sukh", "1": "Sales", "2": "5678"}
    };

    $scope.template = {
  "textboxes": [
   {
     "_id": "tbx0",
     "placeholder": "Department",
     "value": ""
   },
   {
     "_id": "tbx1",
     "placeholder": "Employee ID",
     "value": ""
   },
   {
     "_id": "tbx2",
     "placeholder": "Name",
     "value": ""
   }
  ]
    };
 
 $scope.importables = {
  "0": {"_id": "tbx2"},
  "1": {"_id": "tbx0"},
  "2": {"_id": "tbx1"}
 }
    
    
 $scope.enterImportedData = function() {
  for (var row in $scope.importedData) {
   for (var column in $scope.importedData[row]) {
    console.log($scope.importedData[row][column]);
    for (var i in $scope.template.textboxes) {
     if ($scope.template.textboxes[i]._id === $scope.importables[column]._id) {
      $scope.template.textboxes[i].value = $scope.importedData[row][column];
      console.log($scope.template.textboxes[i]);
      console.log($scope.template.textboxes[i].value);
      break;
     }
    }
    //_.findWhere(template.textboxes, {_id: $scope.importables[column]._id}).value = $scope.importedData[row][column];

   }
  }
 };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<span ng-app="app" ng-controller="ImportCtrl">

        <button
          ng-click="enterImportedData()"
        >
          Import
        </button>
</span>
```

Comment: You do realize that you're using a variable initialized inside a for-loop statement outside the loop right? `for (var i in $scope.template.textboxes)`

The value for `i` will always be the last index of the array/object, hence you're always seeing the last object you imported in the console

Comment: Hi Kaushal, I do see, must have slipped in while i was editing it for stackoverflow. the problem remains the same however. The issue is the same when i use the commented underscore code instead of the for loop.

Comment: when you use `console.log` to output an object, the fields of the object aren't evaluated until you expand the object in the console view.  If you are *re-using* an object, you can output the value of one of the fields, which will show what that field was set to at that moment, but outputting the object, you will see the final state of the object for *every* instance you logged out.  This is one reason that using `console.log` isn't the best for troubleshooting code flow, because it's results can be misleading.

Comment: Thank you! omg, I've been breaking my head over this all day and it was fine all along. I guess the the code snippet thing in here is actually able to output the object in its previous state. I'll think twice about incorrect object values in the future.